# How to apply search filter for only one column using datatables

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I have a table and I'd like to apply a search filter on a specific column. I see a number of links on how to do so but in my code when I insert a javascript block to do the filter, there is nothing that shows up.

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">


  </head>
 <body>
 <table id="example">
   <thead>
   <tr><th>Sites</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr><td>SitePoint</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Learnable</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Flippa</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
  $(function(){
 $("#example").dataTable();
 })
  </script>
```

my confusion is where does this block of code go ( fit in to the main code )?

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" 
     />' );
      } );

   // DataTable
   var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
   table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add a working example?

Answer (score 0):

From their source:

```
$('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true
    } );
```

This piece of code is executed after DOM has been rendered.

Cloning id used to fix the table column names from scrolling off the page.
You need [this script](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js) as well for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a search filter using the datatable search input then you can achieve that by setting the searchable option to false for the rest of columns like this:

```
$('#example').datatable({
    columnDefs: {
       targets: [1,2], // the desired columns
       searchable: false
    }
});
```